# How to improve performance of File::Find::Rule calls?

Tags: perl, file, unix, find, posix

I am using `File::Find::Rule` to locate one-level-deep user-executable folders in a directory specified in `$dir`:

```
my @subDirs = File::Find::Rule->permissions(isExecutable => 1, user => "$uid")->
                                extras({ follow => 1, follow_skip => 2 })->
                                directory->
                                maxdepth(1)->
                                in( $dir );
```

Here is the rough equivalent, using the UNIX `find` utility:

```
my $subDirStr = `find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -user $username -perm -100`;
chomp($subDirStr); 
my @subDirs = split("\n", $subDirStr);
```

Both are run in scripts that have permissions to recover this data.

If I run a `find` statement on the command-line, the results come back instantaneously.

If I run either of the above statements via a Perl script, the results take several seconds to operate.

What can I do programmatically to improve the performance of either of the two Perl approaches?

Comment: You've asked if there are ways to improve on either of the two approaches, but the approach using 'find' comes back immediately. Are you satisfied using an external command to achieve your goal? I'm guessing that File::Find::Rule isn't implemented as efficiently as the find command. If it was me, I'd proceed with the external find command call and not look back.

Comment: Both the `find` and `File::Find::Rule` approaches take several seconds to complete when run through a Perl script. Sorry if this was not clearer.

Comment: There's no reason the same `find` invocation should take several seconds longer to run from Perl than from the shell.  Either there's something else in your script that's actually consuming those seconds, or you're running the Perl script when the directory info is not in cache, and from the shell when the directories have already been cached in memory.

Comment: Removing the `find` call eliminates the delay. There's not much going on downstream after `@subDirs` is populated. NFS caching is not the issue —  I can run a script to eliminate cache between `find` runs.

Comment: You are aware that subsequent `find` sessions are often cached by Bash while each Perl version will not be? The very first call the `find` is probably similar is speed to the Perl version.

Comment: Nope. It runs quickly in between clearing caches, as well as from the first instance.

Comment: @drewk: "cached by *Bash*". Bash does no such thing. Perl shouldn't either. The only caching that happens is due to the kernel directory entry cache.

Comment: You should post more. For example, the results of `time find ...` and `time perl find.pl` where find.pl contains just your `find` invocation and nothing more.

Comment: @thkala: I misspoke about the *owner* of the cache. Not Bash or the shell. However, the concept remains: The subsequent runs of `find` are usually far quicker or instantaneous versus the first run due to OS caching. First run of `find ~ -name "*.txt" -print` on my machine takes 23 secs and the second run (with no context switch) takes 12 secs. If I change a primary, back to 23 secs; second run - 10 to 15 secs.

Comment: Once again: Caching is not the issue. I have a script that clears cache between runs.

Comment: Was my answer helpful at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the delay you are seeing is due to the length of time it takes to produce *all* the results.  Sure, if you pipe your `find` command into `less`, you get results immediately, but if you pipe it into `tail` you might see a delay similar to what you see with your Perl script.

In both your alternative implementations, you are creating an array with a list of all matching files - your code will not continue on until the file matching process is complete.

You could alternatively use an iterator approach like this:

```
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->permissions(isExecutable => 1, user => $uid)
                           ->extras({ follow => 1, follow_skip => 2 })
                           ->directory
                           ->maxdepth(1)
                           ->start($dir);
while( defined ( my $path = $rule->match ) ) {
    ...
}
```

For completeness, you could achieve a similar result with the find command.  Instead of using backticks, you could explicitly use a pipe and read results one at a time:

```
open my $pipe, 'find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -user $username -perm -100|' or die "Can't run find: $!";
while(my $path = <$pipe>) {
    ...
}
```

Note that with both these examples, your code can start processing results as soon as the first match is found.  However, the total time taken until the last result is processed shouldn't be much different to your original code.

Comment: I am not piping results from `find` into `less` or `tail` — the command-line `find` completes its task instantaneously — so this is probably not the issue.

Comment: If you look at File::Find::Rule's source code, you'll see that the iterator approach still reads all matching files into an array before returning the first filename.  There's no performance benefit to using `start` and `match` instead of `in`.  (Other modules like File::Next operate differently.)

Comment: It sounds like I was off base with my guess.  I'm afraid I find the delay you're seeing as mystifying as you do.  If I was trying to diagnose it (on Linux), I'd start by running the code with `strace -t your-script.pl` and perhaps use the Devel::NYTProf profiler ( http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/ ) to see where the delays are occurring.

Comment: @cjm is right. Here's the code for start. Notice it calls "in". It does make you wonder what the point of start and the iterators are.


sub start {
    my $self = _force_object shift;

    $self->{iterator} = [ $self->in( @_ ) ];
    $self;
}

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to ignore the File::Find::Rule part for the moment and focus on the difference in find from the command line vs. find from backticks in perl.

First, please verify that a script that does nothing but the `find...` command still has the problem, run by you as the same user and from and on the same directories as the quickly-running command line invocation.

If it doesn't have the problem, we need to know more about your script.  Or you need to remove things from your script piece by piece until you have it down to just doing the find command, and see what needed to be removed to make the problem go away.

If it does, try using a full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/find`) instead of just `find` to eliminate the possibility of PATH differences or shell aliases causing a difference.

Also check that the output of the command line run and backticks run are identical.

And try redirecting the output of both to /dev/null (inside the backticks, for the perl version) and see if that makes any difference to the timing.

Answer (score 0):

You must realize that calling commands via perl via backticks or system() causes perl to fork off a shell which then runs the desired command.  This will always be slower, though on fast systems with idle resource, it may not be very noticeable.

Comment: Sure, but in Alex's original question, he mentioned that he sees the same delay with File::Find::Rule which doesn't use backticks and doesn't fork a process.